# Changing user passwords while off network with a domain joined laptop (and no VPN access available)

Tags: domain, windows-server, password-management

**Environment**:
2019 Win Server VM - DC/DNS/DHCP roles; has a backup in healthy replication
Sophos NGFW with SSLVPN configured
Remote Desktop works but not via gateway; reliant on SSLVPN connection
AzureAD / Intune MDM setup successfully (SSPR is disabled, AAD/365 MFA required)
MS Entra Sync installed, running and healthy (server->365 only; writeback disabled)

**Situation**:
User needs to change password, cannot connect to VPN due to location restriction, cannot use 365 since writeback is disabled and need to change, call it account security concern because they fell for a phish they realized after handing out their creds (hypothetical but potentially real)

**Knowns**: user can go to a vpn-friendly connection, user can call IT

**Question**:
Can the user change their password on demand as is, excluding known solutions?

Comment: They have to connect to the domain to change the domain password. Any other attempt may lock them out.   You need to see if some way they can get VPN access in.

Comment: are you asking if a user can change a password without access to any of the related identity services? I recall back in the old days (on-prem AD), our remote uses could change their password on their device in a disconnected state, but that that would cause issues when they then did ultimately connect, because the passwords between the laptop and the domain were out of synch. usually at that time we had to force a password change (to get around min-password-age policies) once the user was able to connect to the VPN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my Windows domain password when my PC is not on the domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/75515/how-do-i-change-my-windows-domain-password-when-my-pc-is-not-on-the-domain)